# Issue in Sorting string Date field in google app engine datastore

Tags: google-app-engine

I have given Date field in String type in Google App Engine Datastore. Because of that I am not able to sort date field in any order.

```
Fname = db.StringProperty()
Lname = db.StringProperty()
Date = db.db.StringProperty()   #Format: DD/MM/YYYY
```

Now I can't change date field because I am having around 800 data records in database.

Please help me to sort this problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only a few choices.

1. Change the model to use db.DateProperty
2. Change the format of your string to YYYY-MM-DD
3. Sort the query results in memory with a lambda that converts date strings to real dates when doing the sort comparison.
4. created an additional DateProperty and duplicate the string as a DateProperty

oh and 800 records is not much to convert ;-)  Do it via remote api and you won't have to deploy additional code to perform the conversion.  Though you do need to update your model if you use option 1 or 4.

Comment: Hi Tim, can you please elaborate how to use remote api for my case.

Comment: Have you had a read of this https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api basically it gives you an interactive shell connected to the datastore.  You can query entities/create modify etc....  Have a read, if your not using it already you should be.  You will find you can learn an enormous amount about the platform with the interactive shell.

Comment: Once you work out which strategy you are going to adopt then I can give you a more specific example of how you might use the remote_api_shell, but once you play with it, you can probably work that out for yourself.